# Insert Firestore Document Data from Current User into Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionview

What Im trying to do is retrieve the Firestore data for a specific user (the user's books) and put it on a collection view like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWcFg.png). Currently I can only print the doc data on the console and thats where Im stuck. If you can help this is my Firestore [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sXlG.png) and my code. I didn't insert the collection view code because the collection view cell only has an image view (the books image). Thanks in advance :)

```
func fetchUserBooks() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Firestore.firestore().collection("books").document(uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data()
                print(dataDescription ?? "")
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pod: [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) to decode the document from Firestore. You need to create a struct/class that can hold the data coming from the db.

```
struct Book: Codable {
  var description: String?
  .....
}
```

Afterward, the method fetchUserBooks() could look like this:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("books")....
guard let model = try? FirestoreDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: document.data()) else { return }
```

Keep in mind that you are working with async code, you need to use completion handlers.

Comment: okay so I do have a struct to hold the data called UserBooks and is it possible to do it without pods? I also mentioned that I was able to print out the data on the Xcode console but when i do let genre = dataDescription?[genre] as? String ?? "" is comes back nil. Do you know why?

Comment: @ditto it comes back nil because your `genre` is inside an array in Firestore.

Comment: @Koh how do I fix this

Comment: @ditto I would recommend that one document be one `UserBook` object.